# Am I using the word "superbowls" incorrectly in this statement, even if the answer is singular?

Tags: word-usage, grammatical-number

> The Eagles have won more superbowls this century than the Cowboys....one.

Is the first sentence grammatically correct or is it incorrect to use "superbowls" plurally here because the answer is only one superbowl? I thought because I was refering to two different teams that I should use it plurally but since there has only been one superbowl between the both of them am I using the plural incorrectly??

Comment: It might be semantically quirky, but *syntactically* there's nothing wrong with, say, ***I have more left legs than a snake***. (whether or not it continues ***...but a centipede has more left legs than me*** :)

Comment: The setup has no responsibility for the singular punchline. How many fingers am I holding up? One. No, if I held up one finger, I did not hold up fingers. Really?

Comment: You should capitalise it if you're referring to the annual event between winners of NFL and AFL. If you're using it to mean a general football game, lower case it.

Answer (score 0):

The way I've heard it more often would be:

> The Eagles have won the Superbowl more times this century than the
> Cowboys have - once.

Comment: I agree totally, but an edit to 'Burkina Faso won more Olympic medals at the 2020 Summer Olympics than ever before ... one.' focuses us on the intended question.